# How to exploit kotlin's inline benefits when function has an object with a lambda parameter

Tags: lambda, kotlin, inline-functions

lets say I have a data class like so

```
private data class StubModel<T>(
        val invocation: ItemsFactory.() -> T?,
        val returnValue: T
)
```

and I have a function like so

```
private fun <T> stubIt(stubs: List<StubModel<T>>) {
    for (stub in stubs) {
        whenever(stub.invocation()).thenReturn(stub.returnValue)
    }
}
```

now when I try to the inline the `stubIt` function I dont get any performance benefits (i.e the lambda parameter in the `StubModel` is not inlined which is why I want the power of inline), how do I get kotlin compiler to inline the lambda parameter in the model class at the call site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **not** possible. As a property of your `StubModel`, the `invocation` needs to be an object instance and stored as such. This is just, what *inline* functions are meant for to prevent. Also having a list as a parameter makes it impossible to inline anything, because how should the compiler know about the values at *runtime*.